# post_status in Woocommerce default CSV exporter/importer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is what I have tried to export/import the post_status with the default Woocommerce CSV importer/exporter.

I have managed to get the post_status field to show up mapped in the importer/exporter.
It also exports the column to csv. However there is no data.

How could I get the post_status to export and import correctly?

```
// ADD CUSTOM IMPORT COLUMN TO CSV IMPORTER
add_filter( 'woocommerce_csv_product_import_mapping_options', 'add_column_to_importer' );

function add_column_to_importer ( $options ) {
    $options['post_status'] = 'post_status';
    return $options;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_csv_product_import_mapping_default_columns', 'add_column_to_mapping_screen' );

function add_column_to_mapping_screen ( $columns ) {
    $columns['post_status'] = 'post_status';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_import_pre_insert_product_object', 'process_import', 10, 2 );

function process_import( $object, $data ) {    
    if (!empty($data['post_status'])) {
    $object->post_status($data['post_status']);
  }
    return $object;
}

// ADD CUSTOM EXPORT COLUMN TO CSV EXPORTER
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_column_names', 'add_export_column' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_default_columns', 'add_export_column' );

function add_export_column( $columns ) {    
    $columns['post_status'] = 'post_status';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_custom_column', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );

function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
    $post_status = get_post_status();
    return $post_status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue inside your hooks. Check the last hook, for example. You need to replace `...._custom_column` with your actual column which is in your case `post_status`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_post_status', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );

function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
    return $product->get_status();
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_import_pre_insert_product_object', 'process_import', 10, 2 );
function process_import( $product, $data ) {
    if ( ! empty( $data['post_status'] ) ) {
        $product->set_status( $data['post_status'] );
    }

    return $product;
}
```

This hook is used to add some data to your column and because the hook is incorrect, no data is visible.

Comment: Thanks that returned zeros for published products. I was expecting a value such as "publish" and was hoping to import some products with the post_status value of "trash". Are zeros the expected result?

Comment: You need to map the values by using a switch for example! My code just shows you why you don't see any value - now you can see a value.

Comment: Have done a quick search and come up empty. Would you mind linking me to some documentation that might help me in regards to using a switch? I'm flying blind really. I have just adapted a code that I used previously to export/import a slug column.

Comment: Just saw that you're not passing any object to the `get_post_status` function. Try again. Edit: I've also simplified it a bit for you.

Comment: this now gives the expected export result, still testing the import.

Comment: the import just hangs, could there be something wrong with the ```function process_import```?

Comment: Have you checked your debug.log for any issues?

Comment: Checked your code for import as well since you've only asked for export. There is an issue as well. Maybe better check the WooCommerce class reference next time.

Comment: still getting my head around it all, I've also tried ```return $object->set_status($data['post_status']);```. I will look into enabling the log and check.

Comment: Check my updates answer. Why returning a function call? Makes no sense to me. First you need to call a function to change something and after that you can return the object again. If you check the place where the filter gets applied, everything will makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Still hanging but gets through eventually. That's a different issue though. Will get onto the debug log.